# Add-Migration error: Schema specified is not valid

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, ef-fluent-api

I can not create a new migration `Add-Migration Testing`

## Package version

Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi          ->  *5.0.0-beta1-130515*
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client   ->  *5.0.0-beta1-130515*
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core     ->  *5.0.0-beta1-130515*
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData    ->  *5.0.0-beta1-130515*
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Web...   ->  *5.0.0-beta1-130515*

## Error

When I try to create a new migration the following error occurs:

> PM> Add-Migration Testing System.Data.Entity.Core.MappingException:
>   Schema specified is not valid. Errors:  (0,0) : error
>   2025: XML Schema validation failed for mapping schema. Schema Error
>   Information : The
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2012/10/edm/migrations:IsSystem'
>   attribute is not declared.. (0,0) : error 2025: XML
>   Schema validation failed for mapping schema. Schema Error Information
>   : The
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2012/10/edm/migrations:IsSystem'
>   attribute is not declared.. (0,0) : error 2025: XML
>   Schema validation failed for mapping schema. Schema Error Information
>   : The
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2012/10/edm/migrations:IsSystem'
>   attribute is not declared.. (0,0) : error 2025: XML
>   Schema validation failed for mapping schema. Schema Error Information
>   : The
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2012/10/edm/migrations:IsSystem'
>   attribute is not declared.. (0,0) : error 2025: XML
>   Schema validation failed for mapping schema. Schema Error Information
>   : The
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2012/10/edm/migrations:IsSystem'
>   attribute is not declared.. (0,0) : error 2025: XML
>   Schema validation failed for mapping schema. Schema Error Information
>   : The
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2012/10/edm/migrations:IsSystem'
>   attribute is not declared.. (0,0) : error 2025: XML
>   Schema validation failed for mapping schema. Schema Error Information
>   : The
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2012/10/edm/migrations:IsSystem'
>   attribute is not declared..    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.Init(EdmItemCollection
>   edmCollection, StoreItemCollection storeCollection, IEnumerable`1
>   xmlReaders, IList`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection..ctor(EdmItemCollection
>   edmCollection, StoreItemCollection storeCollection, IEnumerable`1
>   xmlReaders)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.XDocumentExtensions.GetStorageMappingItemCollection(XDocument
>   model, DbProviderInfo& providerInfo)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument
>   sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, ModificationCommandTreeGenerator
>   modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator
>   migrationSqlGenerator)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Scaffold(String
>   migrationName, String namespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder.Scaffold(String
>   migrationName, Boolean ignoreChanges)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Scaffold(MigrationScaffolder
>   scaffolder)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
>   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate
>   callBackDelegate)    at
>   System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Scaffold(String
>   migrationName, String language, String rootNamespace, Boolean
>   ignoreChanges)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name,
>   Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c_*DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b*_0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command)

## Code

The code is quite extensive. These are the last classes that have changed.

```
public class Entidade : EntityNome, IAuditavel
{
    public DateTime CriadoAs { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario CriadoPor { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AtualizadoAs { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario AtualizadoPor { get; set; }
}

public class Empresa : Entidade
{
    public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }
    public string InscricaoEstadual { get; set; }
    public string WebSite { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<Pessoa> Representantes { get; set; }
    public virtual Pessoa Contato { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Telefone> Telefones { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Endereco> Enderecos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Email> Emails { get; set; }
}   

public class Agencia : Empresa
{
    public string Identificacao { get; set; }
    public virtual Regional Regional { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Pessoa> Gerentes { get; set; }
}   

public class Regional : EntityNome
{
    public virtual ICollection<Pessoa> Contatos { get; set; }
}
```

### Configuration

```
public class EntidadeConfiguracao : EntityTypeConfiguration<Entidade>
{
    public EntidadeConfiguracao()
    {
        Property(p => p.Nome).IsName(true);
        HasRequired(p => p.CriadoPor).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        ToTable("Entidades");
    }
}

public class EmpresaConfiguracao : EntityTypeConfiguration<Empresa>
{
    public EmpresaConfiguracao()
    {
        HasMany(p => p.Telefones).WithMany().Map(m => m.ToTable("EmpresaTelefones"));
        HasMany(p => p.Emails).WithMany().Map(m => m.ToTable("EmpresaEmails"));
        HasMany(p => p.Enderecos).WithMany().Map(m => m.ToTable("EmpresaEnderecos"));
        HasMany(p => p.Representantes).WithMany().Map(m => m.ToTable("EmpresaRepresentantes"));

        ToTable("Empresas");
    }
}

public class AgenciaConfiguracao : EntityTypeConfiguration<Agencia>
{
    public AgenciaConfiguracao()
    {
        HasRequired(p => p.Regional).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(true); //.HasForeignKey(p => p.RegionalId)
        Property(p => p.Identificacao).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(10);
        HasMany(p => p.Gerentes).WithMany().Map(m => m.ToTable("AgenciaGerentes"));

        ToTable("Agencias");
    }
}

public class RegionalConfiguracao : EntityTypeConfiguration<Regional>
{
    public RegionalConfiguracao()
    {
        Property(p => p.Nome).IsName(true);
        HasMany(p => p.Contatos).WithMany().Map(m => m.ToTable("RegionalContatos"));

        ToTable("Regionais");
    }
}
```

*Posted on [aspnetwebstack issue](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1052)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recreate your migrations. Take a look at the "Things You Need to Know" section in the [EF6 Beta1 announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/05/30/ef6-beta-1-available.aspx)

Here is a related [work item](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1128) on the EF codeplex site.